# Check if opacity is set

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I have a script that animates opacity but if the opacity has not been previously set then it just disappears. I just wondered if there was a way to check if the opacity has been set. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need to show some code

Comment: All I need to know is how to check if an element.style.opacity has been previously set via CSS. Surely it would not matter what context it was used in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Generally, CSS properties that aren't set return an empty value in JavaScript.</del>

**Update:** It appears that `element.style` will only return values that were previously set via JavaScript *or* specified in the inline style. To get the true value of a CSS property, you need to use the so-called "computed style" of an element.

Here's a function (copied from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)) that does this:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

However, this will return `1.0` (the default value) if the opacity has not been set, so there's really no way to know if the opacity was actually defined in CSS or not.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with isNaN( element.style.opacity ).

Comment: @Christopher W. Allen-Poole: What if it's 0.0?

Comment: Nope, checking if it is an empty string and running it through the isNaN function still return 0.

Comment: @Christopher W. Allen-Poole: I don't think it's any different, considering the value can only be empty or a number. @Robusto: 0.0 is still considered a number.

Comment: Does anyone know what a not set opacity will return? Or a method of determining what it returns?

Comment: @casablanca You're right, it doesn't practically matter here. @Wolfy87 Also correct, that should have been isNaN( parseInt( element.style.opacity ) ); @robusto 0.0, "0.0" and 0/10 are all Numbers. (Though if you call Object.prototype.toString.apply( "0.0" ) it will display [Object String]").

Comment: Well casablanca's function did not work for me, it seems a bit browser specific too. And using isNaN(parseInt(element.style.opacity)) did not do the trick either.

Comment: @Wolfy87: What problem are you having? It seems to work fine for me. It assumes that `el` is the ID of an element, so you would call it as `getStyle('some_id', 'opacity')`.

Comment: Okay, it *was* not working, but after playing about with my code quite a bit I have managed to get it working, thank you very much for that. All sorted!

Comment: One thing: In newer versions of Firefox, `getComputedStyle` gets the unclicked version of a link if there's an `a` and an `a:visited`.